# How to share a post using Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook

Hi Im Currently Trying To Share A Post Via Facebook Graph Api

Is it Possible to Share A Post Via Facebook Graph Api Using The Link Of The post?

Like Using The Link Of The post can i share it via Facebook graph api?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.